# C# Find every number divisible by 3, in a string of numbers

Tags: c#

this is my first post here, I'm new to C# and I have some problems with my code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region FindAllNumbersDivisibleBy3
        Console.Write("Enter a string of numbers: ");
        string Nums = Console.ReadLine();          
        List<long> arr = new List<long>(); 
     
        for (int i = 0; i < Nums.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = Nums.Length - 1; j >= i; j--)
            {
                try
                {
                    string substring = Nums.Substring(i, j);                      
                    if (Convert.ToInt64(substring) % 3 == 0)
                    {
                        arr.Add(Convert.ToInt64(substring));                                                    
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
               
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The following numbers are divisble by 3: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
        
        Console.ReadLine();
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The problem is the following: I'm given a series of numbers, probably too big and inefficient to be stored as an integer, so it's recommended to use a string, and you have to find every single number divisible by three. That could be the entire string, or some sub-strings, or just single digit numbers, etc. I get some conversion errors from the catch exception, as well as something else regarding some length parameter and I don't really understand what's the problem. It's also possible that the for loops' arguments have some errors too, but as far as I'm concerned the problems start in the try block.
Sorry if this is a very dumb question, I'm still in high school so I'm not very good at programming yet. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: performance hint: you are calling `Convert.ToInt64` twice, use `long.TryParse (string, out long number)` on the `if` statement.

Comment: The max value for a long is still just `9223372036854775807`. If the string could be larger, you're gonna need another way (hint: sum each digit, and if the sum is divisible by 3, the original number is also divisible by three).

Comment: @RafaelplayerxdYT is giving great advice, as it also totally eliminates the need for the try/catch block as well.

Comment: @BradleyUffner thank you, i am trying to do my best a programming and helping progrmmers : )

Comment: If the input is "369", is your answer the whole collection of 3, 6, 9, 36, 69, 369?

Comment: This smells a lot like recursion, don't you guys think?

Comment: @Dominique Yes, and I have to print out the numbers on the screen, not just print out "X numbers are divisible by 3"

Answer (score 3):

This is still vulnerable to overflows, but it would take a very long string indeed to reach that point:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a string of numbers: ");
        string Nums = Console.ReadLine();          
        Console.WriteLine("The following numbers are divisble by 3: ");

        foreach(var result in DivisibleByThree(Nums))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> DivisibleByThree(string input)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = input.Length; j > i; j--)
            {
                string segment = input.Substring(i, j-i);                      
                if (SumOfDigits(segment) % 3 == 0)
                {
                    yield return segment;                                                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int SumOfDigits(string digits)
    {
        return digits.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).Select(c => c-'0').Sum();
    }
}
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/KacyAD

---

And since someone suggested recursion, I thought that'd be fun to try. I didn't quite get as far as I wanted (removing both loops and using recursion as the *only* repetition mechanism), but this does work:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DivisibleByThree(string input)
{
    if (input.Length > 1)
    {
       foreach(var item in DivisibleByThree(input.Substring(0, input.Length-1))) 
       {
           yield return item;
       }
    }
    while(input.Length > 0)
    {
        if ( SumOfDigits(input) % 3 == 0) yield return input;
        input = input.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

---

But that's the boring recursion. From a pure performance standpoint, it still spends a lot of time summing the same sequences of digits. There's a probably a way to use recursion to preserve prior work on each recursive call, and in that way make this run *significantly* faster.

That is, rather than start with a big string and check progressively smaller segments, start with the small string and with each check add the sum for the just the additional digit:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DivisibleByThree(string input)
{
    for(int i = input.Length - 1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        foreach(var item in DivisibleByThreeR(input.Substring(i, input.Length - i), 0, 0, 0)) yield return item;
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> DivisibleByThreeR(string input, int startPos, int nextPos, int sum)
{
    sum += input[nextPos] - '0';
    if (sum % 3 == 0) yield return input.Substring(startPos, nextPos - startPos + 1);
    if (++nextPos < input.Length) 
    {
        foreach (var item in DivisibleByThreeR(input, startPos, nextPos, sum)) yield return item;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is really any faster. I didn't benchmark or test at all beyond getting the right result. In fact, I suspect the iterators will eat up any improvements over the pure-loop version.

There's also probably a way to move the loop in the outer method also into the recursive function thereby optimize even further. But it was a nice exercise.

Here's my final fiddle if anyone else wants to play:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/dGFWNx

Comment: If that overflow ever does become an issue, there is always `System.Numerics.BigInteger`.

Comment: Or atleast long instead of int edit: just noticed OP is using long (Convert.ToInt64)

Comment: @RandRandom For the initial value. I only use `int` for the sum of the digits. You'd need a string more than 200 million characters long before that starts to be a problem.

Comment: Can't I dream big? Now in all seriousness, is that really what OP wants, so `99` gettting treated as `18` instead of `99`?

Comment: @RandRandom It's one of those odd number quirks: a number is itself divisible by three if the sum of its digits is divisible by three. So the result is the same.

Comment: Does your code compile? I am getting an error saying char cant be converted to ReadOnlySpan<char> in net6 or string in net5 ? (on `int.Parse(c)`)

Comment: Oh good to know, thx.

Comment: @Rand Try it now. I think I was somehow getting an implicit ToString() in the online repl tool I was using.

Comment: @RandRandom I get the same compiler error when I try this code. "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string' edit: it's fixed with the new version. Thanks everyone

Comment: @MassSpectrometer This is fixed.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you. Now I will try to interpret your code, because it uses many things I haven't learned yet :D

Comment: @MassSpectrometer That's the point ;) I fixed the loop mechanics and overflow issues in the question, but for a learning problem I don't want you just copy/pasting the answer, so I also didn't shy away from techniques that will likely make you puzzle through some things first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution close to your code that uses BigInteger (you need .NET5+). This shall eliminate the risk of running into OverflowException. Please note that there can be duplicates in the output (you didn't say if you want to see them).

```
using System.Numerics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region FindAllNumbersDivisibleBy3
        Console.Write("Enter a string of numbers: ");
        string Nums = Console.ReadLine();
        List<BigInteger> results = new();
    
        for (int i = 0; i < Nums.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = Nums.Length; j >= i; j--)
            {
                try
                {
                    string substring = Nums.Substring(i, j - i);
                    if (BigInteger.TryParse(substring, out var bi) && BigInteger.ModPow(bi, 1, 3).IsZero)
                    {
                        results.Add(bi);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
    
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The following numbers are divisible by 3:");
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(results[i]);
        }
    
        Console.ReadLine();
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something that will work even with numbers other than 3 and 9 would be to implement long division and only keep track of the carry remainder (added a Linq version since it seemed like an appropriate problem for it):

```
static bool IsDivisibleBy(string input, long divBy = 3)
{
    long remainder = 0;
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        var num = Convert.ToInt64(c);
        remainder = ((remainder * 10) + num) % divBy;
    }
    return remainder == 0;
}

static bool IsDivisibleByLinq(string input, long divBy = 3)
{
    return input.Select(c => Convert.ToInt64(c))
                .Aggregate(0L, (remainder, num) => 
                          ((remainder * 10) + num) % divBy) == 0;
}
```